# How to put a 800x600 image in a jLabel without having to scroll to see the whole image

Tags: java, image, jframe, jlabel

i tried ways like getScaledInstance but all does not work. i could not find any solutions online either. the code that i am currently using is:

```
public class ShowImage_1 extends Panel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public ShowImage_1() {
        try {
            File input = new File("C:/Lighthouse.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400, null);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display image");
        Panel panel = new ShowImage_1();

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

it does not show the full image on the panel. any idea on how to go about doing it?

i want to achieve this effect: http://img209.imageshack.us/i/77894822.png/

but what i get now is this: http://img600.imageshack.us/i/19267006.png/

any other code i can use to get that?

Comment: What do you mean "does not show the full image".  Is the panel and the frame large enough?  Could you post a SSCCE?

Answer (score 1):

Make the panel large enough to hold the image.. This may solve your problem

Comment: because the image is generated from Matlab, i cannot control the size. it is too big. i could not make the frame that big

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to a JLabel. Add the label to the frame. Then use:

```
frame.pack();
```

NOT

```
frame.setSize(800, 600);
```

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: public class ShowImage_1 extends Panel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public ShowImage_1() {
        try {
            File input = new File("C:/Lighthouse.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, 400, 400, null);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + ie.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

Comment: @Emily, add  your SSCCE to your original posting, not the comment area.